# Class function changing a list (arguments)

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm programing the PSO algorithm and there is a list of the best global position founded. A function inside a class i have created is changing the argument (this list) in the main function, so it's just destroying my results. I do not know what is happening.

I have to pass the best_particle_vector as an argument in order to do some math so as to calculate new positions and change only the swarm (it self)

Thanks.

```
class Particle():
    def __init__(self):
        self.position, self.velocity = initialize_pos_vel(n_dimension)
        self.best_position = self.position
        self.best_fitness = wish_function(self.best_position)

class Swarm(): #each swarm is a vector of particles
    def __init__(self):
        self.particles = initialize_swarm(n_particles)

    def next_pos_vel(self, best_particle_vector): # calcula as novas posições e velocidade do enxame
        for i in range(n_particles):
            for j in range(n_dimension):

                temp_pos = 0
                temp_vel = 0

                temp_vel += w*self.particles[i].velocity[j] #inertia
                temp_vel += c1*random.random()*(self.particles[i].best_position[j] - self.particles[i].position[j]) #personal
                temp_vel += c2*random.random()*(best_particle_vector[j] - self.particles[i].position[j]) #social

                temp_pos = self.particles[i].position[j] + temp_vel

                if (temp_pos > MAX_position) or (temp_pos < MIN_posion): #max position limit.
                    self.particles[i].position, self.particles[i].velocity = initialize_pos_vel(n_dimension) #novas posicoes e velocidades

                    break


                else:
                    self.particles[i].position[j] = temp_pos #nova posicao
                    self.particles[i].velocity[j] = temp_vel #nova velocidade


        return self


def main():

    swarm = Swarm()
    best_global_particle_vector = swarm.particles[0].best_position #just initialization 


    while k < K+1:


        print " <<< 1 >>> ", best_global_particle_vector, " <<< 1 >>>"
        swarm = swarm.next_pos_vel(best_gloval_particle_vector) #new positions <<<<<<------ problemaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
        print " <<< 2 >>> ", best_global_particle_vector, " <<< 2 >>>"

       ''' ... '''
```

Actual results:

```
<<< 1 >>>  [-56.362471020090446, 48.27571332531588]  <<< 1 >>>
<<< 2 >>>  [-52.75857277952958, 41.70638206522979]  <<< 2 >>>
```

it shouldn't change the list best_particle_vector. it should be:

```
<<< 1 >>>  [-56.362471020090446, 48.27571332531588]  <<< 1 >>>
<<< 2 >>>  [-56.362471020090446, 48.27571332531588]  <<< 2 >>>
```

Comment: Read https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line

```
best_global_particle_vector = swarm.particles[0].best_position #just initialization
```

results in `best_global_particle_vector` and `particles[0].best_position` (which *does* get changed in the method) the same thing.  If you want them to be different, make a copy of `particles[0].best_position`.

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks a lot.  You saved my code.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you understand how referencing works in python. When you do `self.best_position = self.position`, you are pointing both names to the same object, so changing one will change the other (there are many tutorials and Q&As on this).

Short answer, try:

```
self.best_position = list(self.position)    #same values, but two different lists
```

idem:

```
 best_global_particle_vector = list(swarm.particles[0].best_position)
```

(and so on, when you want to copy the values of one list to a new list)

Comment: Thanks a lot. I didn't know that. It's been a while since last time i programed. Really thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't work by itself so I can't check it.

If you can change the code in the method without problems, try adapting it with [Waket's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55593117/11028959). Methods shouldn't change the lists if they really don't have to.

Now if you cannot change the processing code, and you are entering a List that gets modified, you might want to make a [deep copy](https://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html) of it and pass the copy as the parameter.

Here's what I imagine you are doing (this is a Python 3 example):

```py
def list_ruiner(the_list): ## Can't change this for whatever reason
    for i in range(0,len(the_list)):
        the_list[i] += the_list[i] + 1
    return the_list


vulnerable_list = [1,2,3]

# List before:
print(vulnerable_list)

# List data gets ruined by reference
print(list_ruiner(vulnerable_list))

# Original reference is ruined
print(vulnerable_list)
```

Solution:

```py
import copy

def list_ruiner(the_list): ## Can't change this for whatever reason
    for i in range(0,len(the_list)):
        the_list[i] += the_list[i] + 1
    return the_list


vulnerable_list = [1,2,3]

# List before:
print(vulnerable_list)

# Send copy to the function:
print(list_ruiner(copy.deepcopy(vulnerable_list)))

# Original list stays the same
print(vulnerable_list)
```

Comment: I posted an answer like you, but use List Comprehension

Comment: @WaketZheng yeah that works much better if changing code in methods is preferable. I've done it like this because when we are at this level sometimes you just want to deal with input instead of refactoring, god knows what else some methods are gonna do with the altered list.

Answer (score 0):

Origin code:

```
def list_ruiner(the_list):
    for i in range(0,len(the_list)):
        the_list[i] += the_list[i] + 1
    return the_list


vulnerable_list = [1,2,3]

# List before:
print(vulnerable_list)

# List data gets ruined by reference
print(list_ruiner(vulnerable_list))

# Original reference is ruined
print(vulnerable_list)
```

Solution:

```
def list_ruiner(the_list):
    return [v+1 for v in the_list]

vulnerable_list = [1,2,3]

# List before:
print(vulnerable_list)

print(list_ruiner(vulnerable_list))

# Original list stays the same
print(vulnerable_list)
```